# Simplify Swift code

Tags: swift

I'm really new in Swift. I have working code, but it's not very simple. There are many code **"if inside if"**. Can I simplify this code?

```
if let answerMessage = serverResponse["messages"] as? NSDictionary {
  if let answerError = answerMessage["error"] as? NSArray {
    if let answerErrorFirst = answerError[0] as? NSDictionary {
      if let answerErrorMessage = answerErrorFirst["message"] as? String {
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            self._errLabel.text = answerErrorMessage
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
        }

        return
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is much better fit for Code Review...

Comment: First, stop using `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` in Swift. Use a Swift dictionary and a Swift array.

Comment: Google “pyramid of doom”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1/ You can chain those let x = y in the if statement.

2/ forget about NSDictionary and NSArray, Swift has it’s own types. You can specify the type in those. Eg. array of Foo-objects becomes [Foo]. 
You can do the same for dictionaries, both keys and values.

```
if let answerMessage = serverResponse["messages"] as? [AnyHashable:Any],
let answerError = answerMessage["error"] as? [TypeOfObjectsInAnswerMessage],
let answerErrorFirst = answerError.first as? [AnyHashable:Any],
let answerErrorMessage = answerErrorFirst["message"] as? String {
//...
}
```